# Combine Menus in mobile App

Tags: navigation, menu, mobile-application

I have an app with a bottom navigation bar that contains the 5 main features. Now I am increasing the number of features to 7. Is it okay to keep the 5 main features visible in the bottom bar, and to add a hamburger menu for the less important features and settings, legal info, user profile, ...? Or should I move everything into the hamburger menu?

Answer (score 1):

By hiding the main features in the hamburger menu, **you're making those features less visible**.

To quote Don Norman notes in [The Design of Everyday Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1452654123):

> In each state of the system, the user must readily **see and be able to
>   do the allowable actions**. The visibility acts as a suggestion
>   reminding the user of the possibilities.

Instead, have a **hamburger icon in your bottom navigation** and show the less regularly used icons in there.

Facebook uses this exact method to ensure that **all main navigation is accessible from a single menu** (albeit with a modal to dig deeper):

[image: Facebook hamburger menu]

Comment: I thought about adding the hamburger icon to the header (where the magnifying glass icon is in your screenshot). This would free one position in the bottom navigation bar. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Having navigation in two separate locations means there's twice as many places the user has to look for a certain navigation item. If you did opt for this method, put the navigation bar items in the hamburger too. And then your bottom navigation bar essentially becomes a shortcut bar.

Comment: On the other hand, the duplicates would make the hamburger menu longer or even scrollable (on very small devices). That's something that should be considered.